# Does $A \geq B$ imply $I \geq BA^{-1}$?

Tags: matrices, order-theory, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

Using the [Loewner order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loewner_order), if $A \geq B$ and $A$ is invertible, then is $I \geq BA^{-1}$?

Assume all matrix dimensions are $n \times n$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the Loewner order only applies to Hermitian matrices matrices (or matrices whose difference is Hermitian). Given that $A,B$ are Hermitian, $BA^{-1}$ will be Hermitian if and only if $A$ and $B$ commute.

On the other hand: if $A$ is positive definite, then we can indeed say that
$$
A \geq B \implies \operatorname{Id} \geq A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2}.
$$

Comment: thanks, then i cannot find the justification for this transition, maybe you could assist me , for A = VV^t (cholesky deco'), and D diagonal invertible mat'.  why does I>=VV^tD^-1 iff I>=VD^-1V^t ?

Comment: @לנקריתומשר It is not true that I>=VV^tD^-1 iff I>=VD^-1V^t

Comment: @לנקריתומשר As I state in my answer, saying $I \geq BA^{-1}$ is fundamentally problematic

Comment: Even if A is psd and D>=A?

Comment: $D \geq A$ does not allow us to deduce that $I \geq AD^{-1}$.  An example: take
$$
D = \pmatrix{5&0\\0&4}, \quad A = \pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}.
$$
Note that $AD^{-1}$ is not symmetric, so $I \geq AD^{-1}$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks, that helps alot!